# React native , incrementation

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a variable pass and I did a {pass++} inside of one of my return. Howether , while it increment the pass, it also show the pass on my page. How to make it so that it is not on my page?
Here is my code:

```
return (
<View>
  <Text>
    //Here I put some text, then I wanted to increment
    {pass++}
  </Text>
</View>
)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: I have a pass variable (let) and when I do pass+1 inside the View(or the the Text) it show the variable next to my text. Howether it is not what I want, I just want to do pass+1 without having a number in my text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve using 2 `useEffect` hooks:

```
const [pass, setPass] = useState(0);
 
useEffect(() => {
   setPass((prev) => prev + 1);
});

useEffect(() => {
   console.log(pass);
},[pass]);
```

With first one you increment `pass` by one every time `Text` will be rendered; with the second one you print last `pass` value.

Comment: Do you mean that pass wil be incremented by 1 every second without me doing anything? I only wanted it to be incremented by 1 when the text was used

Comment: @Louis What do you mean "when the text was used"? When it is rendered? Every time it is rendered?

Comment: Yes, every time it is rendered

Comment: No problem. Have a nice coding =)

Comment: Shouldn't it be setPass((pass) => pass + 1); instead of setPass((prev) => prev + 1); ?

Comment: `prev` or `pass` is the same: I wrote `prev` because it's the previous value of `pass`